# frontend support for MLIR?

Tags: clang, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

Is there any frontend that will generate MLIR (not LLVM) code currently? I am interested in parsing C/C++ or Java code in particular. Does clang support this now? [This page](https://mlir.llvm.org/users/) doesn't list any at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

As of Oct 2020, compiling C++ into `CIL` (C intermediate language) mlir dialect is not public yet. But they will be making it available "soon".
This was hinted on this year on LLVM developers meeting (http://llvm.org/devmtg/2020-09/program/) on the following talk:

- CIL : Common MLIR Dialect for C/C++ and Fortran - P. NR; V. M; Ranjith; Srihari

In case people are not aware, as an alternative if you just want your C/C++ code in the mlir environment is to compile your program into LLVM with `clang -S -fno-discard-value-names -emit-llvm` and then later use `mlir-translate --import-llvm` to transform your `.ll` file into a `.mlir` file. But you do lose some higher level information and the opportunity for higher level optimizations.